# Cannot insert partialview data after calling it with jQuery get method in main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a partial view to show selected index change data in my main page. I want to insert partialview data to main view model table, but partialview data is not inserted. How is it possible to insert partialview data and main view data at a time after clicking insert button?

Here is my `partialview`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.test_item_name)
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.item_check, new {id = "itemcheckbox", name = "c", groupname = "b"})

                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.item_check, new{id="itemcheckbox1", name = "c", groupname = "b"})
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Here is my `MainView`:

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#testhead').on('change',function () {
                $('#testname').text($('option:selected', $(this)).text());

                var selectedID = $(this).val();

                $.get('/Test_result/GetTestItem/' + selectedID, function(data) {

                    /* data is the pure html returned from action method, load it to your page */
                    $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
                    /* little fade in effect */
                    $('#partialPlaceHolder').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetTestItem(int id = 0) {
    List<tbl_test_item> list = db.tbl_test_item.Where(item => item.test_head_id == id).ToList();

    ViewBag.result_type= db.tbl_test_head.Where(item => item.test_head_id == id);
    return PartialView("_TestItem", list);
}
```

Comment: This can't be your entire `MainView`. Where are the elements with id's `testhead`, `testname`, and most importantly, `partialPlaceHolder`?

Comment: Is there any error?